# Angular Js - Why the call for the first <li> is not going?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have been stuck for more than an hour and I could not figure it out what is the issue. I have a simple code in which I am using `ng-repeat`.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="width-100" ng-repeat="results in cats">
        {{cats.indexOf(results)}}
        <a class="pd-left-0 pd-right-0 cursor-pointer" ng-click="product_count(cats.indexOf(results))" data-toggle="tab">
            <img src="img/categories/{{results.id}}.png" class="sidebar-tabs"><span> {{cats.indexOf(results)}}</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In the `ng-click` function I am sending the `index` it works perfectly fine for the `indexes greater than 0` . I mean when the function has value `product_count(1 or greater but not 0)` the function is called and the API is hit. But there is a strange behaviour I am experiencing. When the `function` has value `product_count(0)` the function is not called nor does the API get hit. Why is this happening?

product count function

```
 $scope.product_count = function (category_id) {
        if (category_id) //only do this if i HAVE category_id
        {
            console.log(category_id);
            $scope.category_id = $scope.cats[category_id].id;
            console.log($scope.category_id);

            $http.get('category-product/' + $scope.category_id,
                    {headers:
                                {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                                    'Authorization': $rootScope.keyword_auth_token, 'Accept-Language': $cookies.get('type')}
                    })
                    .success(function (data) {
                        $scope.total_products = data;
                        console.log($scope.total_products);

                    })
                    .error(function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    });
        }
        ;
    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your

```
if (category_id)
```

results in false, which does not execute if statement,as 0 is alias for false, so it will never execute, instead you should check if category_id is equal to ''
use

```
if(category_id=='')
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Comment: why it was returning false ? although country_id had a value but whyyy